# Puppet: Create user account and use its UID/GID in dependent resource

Tags: puppet

I would like Puppet to do the following on the host:

- Ensure a user named `myuser` exists.

  - I don't want to hardcode the UID as there are several users created this way.
- Use the UID of `myuser` in a shell script (unfortunately username won't do).

So far I have:

```
user { 'myuser':
    ensure => present,
    system => true,
}

file { '/opt/myuser-uid':
    ensure   => file,
    contents => User['myuser']['uid'],
}
```

However, the file contents ends up blank.

How can I write the newly created UID to a file?

Comment: Is it populated on a second run? Remember Puppet is declarative so if the resource doesn't exist at catalog compile-time then it won't be in the file. But I'd expect it to appear subsequently.

Comment: No, it looks like `User['myuser']` only contains what I put in there, and not the UID.

Comment: In which case you either need to write a custom fact, or manage the user's ID I think.